# How to check if a user is following you on twitter?

Tags: ios, ios5, twitter, twitter-follow

[I know how to create a "Follow me" button on Twitter](https://github.com/chrismaddern/Follow-Me-On-Twitter-iOS-Button/), but I only want to display it if the user is not already following me. Is there a way to do this properly?

Answer (score 0):

You can get a list of your own followers' ids using this endpoint: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/followers/ids

If you know their twitter handle, you can get the id of someone using your app using this endpoint: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/users/lookup

Then your button display code will look something like:

```
if ([arrayOfFollowerIds containsObject:idOfAppUser]){

    followButton.hidden = YES;

}
```